# Can't ping 8.8.8.8 on Marriott hotel wifi

Tags: wifi, curl

I have an embedded Linux device (i.e. no display) I'm working on. I can connect to the hotel Wifi (which doesn't have a password) and get an IP address:

```
# ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr REMOVED  
          inet addr:172.20.2.27  Bcast:172.20.15.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1587 (1.5 KiB)  TX bytes:6356 (6.2 KiB)
```

but `ping 8.8.8.8` doesn't work. This device works fine on other Wifi networks.

Answer (score 1):

Hotel Wifi with no password usually uses some sort of forwarding and this works fine on my laptop and phone (if not you can use http://neverssl.com/ to trigger the login screen). But on a headless device I can't do this.

I tried `curl -L google.com` (where the `-L` turns on redirects) and got:

```
<HEAD><TITLE>Redirecting...</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Wed, 26 Feb 1997 08:21:57 GMT">
</HEAD><BODY>
<SPAN STYLE="font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
</SPAN>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
document.location.href="https://dalan.cust.blueprintrf.com:8001/index.php?zone=guest&redirurl=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F";
</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Looking at https://dalan.cust.blueprintrf.com:8001/index.php?zone=guest&redirurl=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F on my laptop in incognito mode goes to another page with the popup I need:
[image: Popup]

If I right-click Inspect (on Chrome) I can see this button is part of a form that does a POST with a bunch of preset variables:

```
<form name="form-lower-plan" class="js-form-sign-in" action="https://dalan.cust.blueprintrf.com:8001" method="post" novalidate="">
    <div class="l-center-align l-margin-bottom-five-quarters l-padding-five-quarters t-bg-standard-30"> 
        <p class="t-font-weight-semibold t-font-l t-line-height-xxxl l-margin-top-none l-margin-subsection-bottom-small"> Internet </p>
        <div class="l-margin-subsection-bottom-small">
            <p class="l-margin-none t-font-s">Free for everyone</p>
            <p class="l-margin-none t-font-s">Best for: email, web browsing</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="l-margin-bottom-five-quarters ">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAC_ADDRESS" value="REMOVED">
        <input type="hidden" name="AUTO_AUTH_STATUS" value="NEW">
        <div class="l-form-group">
            <input id="id-remember-device-free-plan" type="checkbox" name="REMEMBER_THIS_DEVICE" value="TRUE">
            <label for="id-remember-device-free-plan" class="t-label-standard-100 l-margin-none"> Connect with one click at future stays </label>
        </div> <p class="t-font-xs t-line-height-xs l-margin-top-five-quarters">Connect faster whenever a free connection is available. Sign in to your Marriott Bonvoy account on the next screen to automatically receive free internet during your stays.</p>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="AUTH_ON_FREE" value="FALSE">
    <input type="hidden" name="ROOM_NUMBER" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="LAST_NAME" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="CURRENCY" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="PROPERTY_CODE" value="DALAN">
    <input type="hidden" name="iZONE" value="GUEST">
    <input type="hidden" name="iRELEASE" value="4">
    <input type="hidden" name="OTHER_PLAN" value="P_PLAN2">
    <input type="hidden" name="OTHER_PLAN_PRICE" value="4.95">
    <input type="hidden" name="SELECTED_PLAN" value="P_PLAN1">
    <input type="hidden" name="SELECTED_PLAN_PRICE" value="0.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="SELECTED_PLAN_TEXT" value="Internet Services">
    <input type="hidden" name="DURATION" value="7">
    <div class="l-center-align ">
        <button class="m-button m-button-primary l-padding-left-seven-quarters l-padding-right-seven-quarters l-padding-top-three-quarters l-padding-bottom-three-quarters" type="submit">Connect Now</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

From this I can see:

1. It's a POST.
2. The URL is https://dalan.cust.blueprintrf.com:8001
3. There's a bunch of parameters set to default values.

I use this to call the form in curl:
`curl -L -d "AUTH_ON_FREE=FALSE&ROOM_NUMBER=&LAST_NAME=&CURRENCY=USD&PROPERTY_CODE=DALAN&iZONE=GUEST&iRELEASE=4&OTHER_PLAN=P_PLAN2&OTHER_PLAN_PRICE=4.95&SELECTED_PLAN=P_PLAN1&SELECTED_PLAN_PRICE=0.00&SELECTED_PLAN_TEXT=Internet Services&DURATION=7" -X POST https://dalan.cust.blueprintrf.com:8001`

which returns:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
 <HTML>
<HEAD><TITLE>Redirecting...</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Wed, 26 Feb 1997 08:21:57 GMT">
</HEAD><BODY>
<SPAN STYLE="font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
</SPAN>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
document.location.href="https://www.marriott.com/hotels/einterface/DALAN?MAC_ADDRESS=REMOVED&REMEMBER_THIS_DEVICE=&AUTO_AUTH_STATUS=&OTHER_PLAN=P_PLAN2&iRELEASE=4&iZONE=GUEST&CURRENCY=USD&SELECTED_PLAN_PRICE=0.00&DURATION=7&SELECTED_PLAN=P_PLAN1&AUTH_ON_FREE=FALSE&ACTION_TYPE=FREE&LSP_URL=dalan.cust.blueprintrf.com:8001&OTHER_PLAN=P_PLAN2";
</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

and now I can ping 8.8.8.8 and google.com!